# How can I upload an InMemoryUploadedFile to Amazon s3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I am trying to uplaod an image onto Amazon s3. The image is in the object "request.FILES['image']" as can be seen in the code below. My problem is that the boto3 "upload_file()" function expects a path to the image and I on the other hand have an in memory image objects and because of that i get this error.`raise ValueError('Filename must be a string')
ValueError: Filename must be a string`

My code here.

```js
@csrf_protect
def file_upload_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        img_list = request.FILES['image']

        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        s3.upload_file(img_list, settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, img_list.name)
    else:
        print('not post...')
    return HttpResponse([{}], content_type='application/json')
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You can (and should) use forms when dealing with any user input. Having a `FileField()` that uses the `boto3` backend will make saving files to an S3 bucket very simple.

Comment: I am using forms, thought the line "img_list = request.FILES['image']" would make that obvious. But yeah, I am using forms.

Comment: If you are using (django) forms, then you shouldn't be accessing `request.FILES` directly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the **upload_fileobj** function, not the **upload_file**.

**upload_file** is waiting for a path to find a file on disk while **upload_fileobj** is waiting for a file like object.

More information on the [official documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj).